# React jest - getting error text should be deeply equal

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

am getting this error always while running jest testcase with react

```
should render the component without errors:
   AssertionError: expected '  Upload Image' to deeply equal ' Upload Image'
   + expected - actual
   -  Upload Image
   + Upload Image
```

My code look like

```
expect(button.text()).to.eql('  Upload Image');
```

i had given toBe,toEqual,to.equal,to.match.

Can guys help me to resolve

Comment: .toContain('Upload Image') - does that work?

Comment: Isn't there extra space before text? Is it intentional?

Comment: `toEqual` should work. How do you render button element mount/shallow/renderer?

Comment: I had used mount@Jai

Comment: when i gave .toContain ,its saying invalid Chai property. Do you mean contain

Comment: As per the error: the expected text according to your code is `Upload Image` with two leading spaces, but the text it found only has a single leading space. So... just fix that?

Comment: Those two strings are not equal since first one has double space in it. You can use contains if double space is intentional or trim the string.

Comment: @MarkoMarinovic in browser when i inspect its like this &nbsp;&nbsp;Upload Image

Comment: can you try `expect(button.text().trim()).to.eq('Upload Image')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trim your button text and them compare it with 'Upload Image'

```
expect(button.text().trim()).to.eq('Upload Image')
```

Answer (score -1):

It works with

```
expect(button.text().trim().contains('Upload Image');
```